# How to debug this injected dll in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, clr

"the breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols loaded for this document c++"

what I have tried are :

1. created a new configration, and set name as "Debug" (because the source code has no debug configration)
2. set "configration property -> Debugging -> command" to "D:\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe"
3. set "Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debugger Info" to "Generate Debug Information (/DEBUG)"
4. set "Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Programe Database File" to "$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb"
5. build
6. start the game
7. inject the dll file
8. after dll works , i attach the progress in "Debug -> attach to process"
9. set a break point

after i attach the process , i could not find the dll in the modules list. but the dll function is working good.

but i can not debug it.there is a warrning on the break point, says
"the breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols loaded for this document c++"

dll source code is here

https://github.com/R3nzTheCodeGOD/R3nzSkin

Comment: Looks like the injector uses CLR which was not mentioned in the question: [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/R3nzTheCodeGOD/R3nzSkin/main/R3nzSkin_Injector/R3nzSkin_Injector.vcxproj](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/R3nzTheCodeGOD/R3nzSkin/main/R3nzSkin_Injector/R3nzSkin_Injector.vcxproj)

Comment: sorry, i dont know what is that mean. it is a problem ?

Comment: I mean you tagged the question for standard / native `c++` but the injector uses CLR / .net. Not all people with standard c++ experience will use CLR so you may want to indicate in your question that CLR is used. I edited the tags. I am such a person with 30+ years of experience in  native / standard c++ on ms windows but I don't use CLR at all so I could not help.